# Importing Package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, dart-pub

I have an issue to solve an error which I am facing past 3 days, begin the journey in coding since months but I can't get Errors. Here is the Snippet of Todo List code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "TODO",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:  ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        accentColor: Colors.purple,

      ), 
    home: todoui(),
    );

  }
  
  }
```

And I am facing issues for showing me errors, could anyone help me out of this?

I tried to find over the forums of flutter which I thought it would be helpful, but it didn't work.

Comment: can you please identify whats the error and at wich point you are getting this error

Comment: I am receiving error in importing flutter package which I assumed that all default packages are successfully installed, but I was wrong. To be specific this code is not working on my system. To be specific I am getting error in, import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Comment: Please read this to how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried to search everywhere but I didn't get any answers. Let me just try once more and comeback

Comment: your question is not clear we dont know what is error and when it is appearing

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: - Adil Shinwari sir, I provided you the code and I am sorry that I am not able to post the screenshot over this comment. If it possible I don't know how to post Screenshot on comments. Ad if you know, please help me out.

Comment: Please share your todoui() code for better understanding of your problem statement

Answer (score 0):

I see the declaration of `StatefulWidget`, O mean there is a base widget class and there is a `State` object class, but the widget class extends `StatelessWidget`, well this is wrong since it don't have a state:

you will need to just change the first line to this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { // here
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "TODO",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:  ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        accentColor: Colors.purple,

      ), 
    home: todoui(),
    );

  }
  
  }
```

this is a `StatefulWigdet` and it will work

However if you was trying to refactor it to a `StatelessWidget`, then you should make it like this:

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget  {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "TODO",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme:  ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        accentColor: Colors.purple,

      ), 
    home: todoui(),
    );

  }
  
  }
```

Comment: I just copied the code and tried to run the entire code that you have mention, I am still getting errors. is there any possibilities?

Comment: just change the `MyApp` class with this code, but let the main() and the imports as they are on top of your file

Comment: -Gwhyyy Should I need to add constructor? Because it is asking me to add that.

Comment: can you share with me the current full code you tried again ?

Comment: But how? is it possible to paste entire code in the comment?

Comment: no just copy it and paste it in https://gist.github.com/, then give me it's link

Comment: can you share the github link of that repo

Comment: https://gist.github.com/manishN1999/f3935b419e5439bc9d13f403bcd07c54

Comment: try this it will work https://gist.github.com/anasfik/7b7f323b11d57306daf6bdd924866189

Comment: let me know if it does

Comment: i just copied the entire code to the vs code and i am getting error in home: todoui(),

Comment: -Gwhyy Can u mail me?  mnair4429@gmail.com. Here's my mail ID

Comment: didn't todoui() exists in some other file in your project ?

Comment: yes sure, I will

Comment: -Gwhyy Nope, Never

Comment: Did u got any possibilities?